# Is there a way to disable Connectify Lite update monit?

Tags: windows-7, connectify

As in the title, is there a way to disable either the update checks or that annoying monit I have to close every time I launch Connectify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only (but efficient) way I know is to avoid Connectify from contacting the update server:

1. Click Start → Run (or press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Enter `\Windows\system32\Drivers\etc`
3. In the opened folder, there is a file named "hosts"
4. Copy the file "hosts" to your desktop
5. Open it with Notepad
6. After the last line of the file, paste the following:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 updates.connectify.me
   ```
7. Save the file*
8. Drag the file back to the folder you copied it from (drag it holding the right button) and REPLACE the original file. You will need Administrator rights to do this.
9. After this, you will no longer see the update window.

*After saving the file, you must remove the ".txt" extension from its name, so it will be named only "hosts".

[image: Renaming hosts file]

Otherwise, Windows will not use it as the hosts file.
If you can't see file extensions, you must set Windows to show file extensions:

a) Open a window in file explorer

b) Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>

c) Click Tools > Folder Options

d) Click on the second tab "Show" and scroll down the list

e) **Uncheck** the option "Hide extensions for known file types" and click OK. See image below for help:

[image: Setting Windows to show file extensions]

Comment: Thank you Sir for the detailed answer, may I also ask how does one acquire the domain address to be blocked?

Comment: To get the domain address you can use a network monitor, which will show you the domains Connectify will try to contact.
ESET Antivirus has a network monitor by default. You can download it and use for 30 days for free.

Answer (score 4):

The above answer is good, but I would also add the following to the host file:

```
127.0.0.1 downloads2.connectify.me
127.0.0.1 www.connectify.me
```